# how do we do JSX stylings in react js

Tags: reactjs

The errorClr doesn't work.I'm passing the error to it and declared
In render I've

```
const { error }=this.state;
const  {errorClr}={style:{color : {error}}}; // this doesnt work the way?

<div className="col-8" {...errorClr}>Please enter valid data</div>
```

The color property doesn't reflect.I've done no **setstate**. Can we not do something of this sort **{style:{color : {error}}}** ? Whats the other way?
Stylings not getting applied.

Comment: By writing `const {errorClr}=` you try to destructure the `errorClr` property out from `{style:{color : {error}}}`. You want to write `const errorClr = {style:{color : {error}}};`instead.

Comment: @Tholle doesnt work:( doesnt reflect the color onto the text. can u please explain --->const {errorClr}= you try to destructure the errorClr property out from {style:{color : {error}}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write style like this:

```
const { error } = this.state;

<div className="col-8" style={{color:error}}>Please enter valid data</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
const  {errorClr}={style:{color : {error}}};
```

you are trying to destructure `errorClr` from the object `{style:{color : {error}}}` which obviously doesn't exist. You should instead write

```
const  errorClr = {style:{ color :  error }};
```

[**Working demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/lln6nk51yq)

or you can simply write

```
<div className="col-8" style={{color:error}}>Please enter valid data</div>
```